# What is the rate of increase of its area at the moment when the side is 16cm long?

Tags: calculus

A square plate of metal is expanding under the action of heat, and its side is increasing at the uniform rate of 0.1 cm per hour. What is the rate of increase of its area at the moment when the side is 16cm long?

Comment: Is only *one* side of the square increasing?

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189)  **This is not a do-my-homework site**.
Please read [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) and the others
there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people
will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation,
and an explanation of your own attempts, e.g. write out formulae like $A(x) = ?$, translate info into math: $x'(t) = 0.1$, try calculating $A'(t) = ???$, and show where you're stuck/ask for verification.

Comment: @ellesalazar Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Let

- $A(t)=(L_0+0.1\cdot t)^2$
- $A'(t)=2\cdot (L_0+0.1\cdot t)\cdot 0.1$

with

- $(L_0+0.1\cdot t)=16$

Answer (score 0):

$A=a^2$

$\dfrac{dA}{dt}=2a\dfrac{da}{dt}$

put $a=16$ and and $\dfrac{da}{dt}=0.1$

$\dfrac{dA}{dt}=3.2 cm^2/sec$